# addAll() method not working?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

so maybe I'm not using the method how it's intended to be used but a video I watched by youtube user thenewboston used it exactly like this and it worked just fine. Help would be appreciated

```
package checkers;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javafx.scene.Scene  ;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;


public class Checkers extends Application {

    Stage window;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Title");

        HBox layout = new HBox();
        Button  startButton = new Button("Start");
        Button quitButton = new Button("Quit");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(startButton, quitButton);

        Scene startScene = new Scene(layout, 400, 300);

        window.setScene(startScene);
        window.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

`

The error I am receiving is as follows - 
"The method addAll(int, Collection) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Button, Button)"

Comment: What do you think the error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: I am aware that I am not using a Collection as a parameter, but casting them as one did not work. My question has been solved now though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported the wrong type of `Button`.  You want `import javafx.scene.control.Button;` not `import java.awt.Button;`

Comment: The same also true of `import java.awt.BorderLayout`. that should be `import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane`, though that won't cause an error as you aren't using the imported classes currently anyway.  Also similar for `java.awt.FlowLayout`.  Basically, don't import `awt` classes into a JavaFX program unless you are mixing JavaFX and awt/swing code (which is very rare).